# How to automatically refresh page with Laravel PJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a written script in Laravel, and used PJAX plugin for a Navigation. Everything is working fine in my local environment. I have deployed that larvael project on a shared hosting and I am facing a problem with AJAX navigation. Sometimes PJAX works as expected, but something it reloads the entire page and then redirects to home.

The only thing I come up with error_logs is

```
[23-Aug-2017 17:31:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/apc.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/apc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

But I don't think so this has concern with laravel PJAX navigation for demo link of the project website is mentioned below
http://shiamp3.com/beta

Just click on any image below "Top Charts" Rest Navigation will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think below link can solve your issue

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-no-debug-non-zts.207682/

UPDATE:

When you click on the first Image it loads perfectly fine and by clicking on the 3rd image then it generates the error and according to error this issue is with "reciters" or some object written in your view file. you can check "/home/shiampco/public_html/lcore/storage/framework/views/25f42ae4cb490fb2a12705c3c08006243058b97d.php" file from cache , It will give you  rough Idea about which variable is missing/which object is undefined.

Comment: Does dynamic library has any concern with AJAX based Navigation system ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in  $(document).on('pjax:complete') it was defined multiple times at multiple places that's why and timeout was 2s before now it is increased everything seems perfect now :)